# Flutter android license status unknown while executing command

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I started the **Flutter** installation. I set all variables and **Flutter** SDK.
But when I write the command I got the below error.

```
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
    [ΓêÜ] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601],
        locale en-US)
    [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
    
        X Android license status unknown.
          Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
          See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for
    
          more details.
    [!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
        X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
        X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    [!] Android Studio
        X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
        X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
        X android-studio-dir = C:\Program
        X Android Studio not found at C:\Program
    [ΓêÜ] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

To solve the first error I wrote the below command and got the error.

**flutter doctor --android-licenses**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annota
tion/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(Sc
hemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHa
ndler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.j
ava:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.j
ava:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema

        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinCla
ssLoader.java:606)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(C
lassLoaders.java:168)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 5 more
```

But there is no option for Y/N.

Please help me who knows the answer.

Comment: how's your `flutter doctor` after run `flutter --android-licenses` ?

Comment: I already mentioned what's the result of flutter doctor --android-licenses in the question above.

Comment: do you install it with android studio?

Comment: Yes, I installed it with Android Studio.

Comment: have you do these of code to configure your sdk?
`flutter config --android-sdk /path/to/android/sdk`
`flutter config --android-studio-dir /path/to/android/studio`

Comment: Yes, already did that.

Comment: I don't find any issue like yours after did these two steps. may you can send issue at flutter github

Comment: okay thanks, I will post my issue there.